# Conversion from kilograms to grams - JAVA

Tags: java

(Conversion from kilograms to grams). Write a program that displays the follow table( note that 1 kilogram is 1000 grams)

Kilograms   Grams
1           1000
2           2000
...
24          24000
25          25000

As this question covers a chapter on Loops I am looking for help in solving this with the use of a loop.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a homework problem with no attempt at a solution.

Comment: It's not a homework problem. It's just from a chapter. Plus I had no idea where to start with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
System.out.println("Kilograms   Grams");
for (int i =1; i<=25;i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + i*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void display_value_in_g(int kgrams){

int grams = kgrams * 1000;

System.out.println(String.valueof(grams));

}
```

Above code should work fine